# Can Desire2Learn send grade comments with grade values via the valence API?

Tags: api, desire2learn, valence

I see that with the valence API grade data can be sent back to my SIS from D2L. So far everything I have looked at indicates how I can get the grade data, but nothing addresses getting the grade comments or Private Grade Comments. Is it possible to pass this information via the API?

Thanks,
Vickie

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to retrieve grade comments for assigned grade values through the Valence Learning Framework API. I would encourage you to register your request for this feature enhancement with Desire2Learn's [Product Idea Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394).